# Passing keywords as parameters

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

Is it against Python "style" to put keywords as function parameters?
e.g.

```
def findStartTime(dict):
  for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    #do something based on values in dictionary
  return something
```

...and besides style, 
are there any potential problems that will show up?

Comment: No.  Don't do this.  This can have very very bad implications. Instead use a useful param name.  i.e. `users_dict`

Comment: Why don't you try it to see what happens?

Comment: It's against Python style to mask built-in functions (`dict` is a type and function, not a language keyword) anywhere in your program. As @KronoS says, you should be using more descriptive names anyway.

Comment: @Will I'm running it now so I believe it works, but based on the response there must be cases where it doesn't.

Comment: The cases where it doesn't work are the cases where you try to refer to the built-in function `dict()` within `findStartTime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if for some reason in the future you want to call dict() inside the function to create a dictionary? Anyway, give meaningful names to variables instead of naming them by their type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue come down to scope.  If you call something `dict`, you wont be able to access `dict` methods.

For example, if you called a variable `math` then you would be unable to access `math.method()`:

```
>>> import math
>>> math = "MATH"
>>> rounded_number = math.floor(3.14)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'floor'
>>> import math
>>> rounded_number = math.floor(3.14)
>>> rounded_number
3.0
```

So I import math, but then override the module with a string.  Hence the `AttributeError`

Then I reimport `math` and boom, `math.floor()` is a valid method again.  So basically, if you call a `dict` "dict" it will prevent using the `dict()` constructor and other methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is potentially better as you provide an example, but it doesn't need the response to my comment (people will not understand what context you are coming from).